# Ansible playbook not running in GitHub Actions

Tags: ansible, github-actions

I am writing an Ansible playbook to quickly install and configure a local laptop. I have tested it on my local machine with `ansible-playbook local.yml --ask-become-pass` and in a Vagrant box with `vagrant provision`, and that works perfectly. (please keep reading)

`local.yml`

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - common
    - development
  connection: local
  become: yes
...
```

`ansible.cfg`

```
[defaults]
INVENTORY = inventory.yml
INTERPRETER_PYTHON = auto
LOCALHOST_WARNING = False
```

`inventory.yml`

```yaml
---
all:
  children:
    ungrouped:
      hosts:
        default:
          ansible_connection: local
...
```

`Vagrantfile`

```rb
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"

  config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "local.yml"
  end

end
```

Now I want to add a GitHub Action to use GitHub as a CI for my changes, by running my playbook on the latest Ubuntu version inside a container. See GitHub Marketplace: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/check-ansible-ubuntu-latest

`.github/workflows/ansible-ubuntu-latest.yml`

```yaml
name: Ansible check ubuntu:latest

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: ansible check with ubuntu:latest
      uses: roles-ansible/check-ansible-ubuntu-latest-action@master
      with:
        targets: "local.yml"
        hosts: "localhost"
```

However, the playbook doesn't run in GitHub Actions.

This is the relevant part of the log where I think the issue occurs:

```
Warning: : Unable to parse /github/workspace/host.ini as an inventory source
Warning: : No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
Warning: : provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that
the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
```

Please note that I have no `host.ini`, I have a `inventory.yml` instead.

This is the full log of that build step:

```
Run roles-ansible/check-ansible-ubuntu-latest-action@master
/usr/bin/docker run --name b361ed873671b7a624a4eaa4c28615bfd1d98_4e9c36 --label 7b361e --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e INPUT_TARGETS -e INPUT_HOSTS -e INPUT_GROUP -e INPUT_REQUIREMENTS -e TARGETS -e HOSTS -e GROUP -e REQUIREMENTS -e HOME -e GITHUB_JOB -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER -e GITHUB_RUN_ID -e GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER -e GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_SERVER_URL -e GITHUB_API_URL -e GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_ACTION_REF -e GITHUB_PATH -e GITHUB_ENV -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN -e ACTIONS_CACHE_URL -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/ansible-workstation/ansible-workstation":"/github/workspace" 7b361e:d873671b7a624a4eaa4c28615bfd1d98
+ git submodule update --init --recursive
+ [[ '' == *.yml ]]
+ '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+ '[' /ansible-docker.sh = /ansible-docker.sh ']'
+ echo -E '\nRunning Ansible debian check...\n'
\nRunning Ansible debian check...\n
+ ansible::prepare
+ : local.yml
+ : /github/workspace
+ pushd /github/workspace
/github/workspace /github/workspace
+ tee ansible.cfg
+ echo -e '
[defaults]
inventory = host.ini
nocows = True
host_key_checking = False
forks = 20
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /github/home/facts
fact_caching_timeout = 7200
stdout_callback = yaml
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
ansible_connection=local
'

[defaults]
inventory = host.ini
nocows = True
host_key_checking = False
forks = 20
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /github/home/facts
fact_caching_timeout = 7200
stdout_callback = yaml
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
ansible_connection=local

+ echo -e '[local]\nlocalhost ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3 ansible_connection=local'
+ tee host.ini
[local]
localhost ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3 ansible_connection=local
+ [[ local.yml == *.yml ]]

+ echo -e '\nansible playbook detected\ninitialize playbook testing...\n'
ansible playbook detected
initialize playbook testing...

/github/workspace /github/workspace /github/workspace
+ ansible::test::playbook
+ : local.yml
+ : /github/workspace
+ : localhost
+ : ''
+ pushd /github/workspace
+ echo -e '[]\nlocalhost ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3 ansible_connection=local ansible_host=127.0.0.1'
+ tee host.ini
+ ansible-playbook --connection=local --inventory host.ini local.yml
[]
localhost ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3 ansible_connection=local ansible_host=127.0.0.1
Warning: :  * Failed to parse /github/workspace/host.ini with ini plugin:
/github/workspace/host.ini:1: Invalid section entry: '[]'. Please make sure
that there are no spaces in the section entry, and that there are no other
invalid characters
Warning: : Unable to parse /github/workspace/host.ini as an inventory source
Warning: : No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
Warning: : provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that
the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
```

What do I need to change to make sure that my playbook runs in GitHub actions?

Comment: The inventory file used by this action seems [completely hard-coded](https://github.com/roles-ansible/check-ansible-ubuntu-latest-action/blob/5c775457431b589c763f6067bf688e9f45d4bd97/ansible-docker.sh#L20)

Comment: I see, yes. Meanwhile I have added some random `group` in the `with` of `ansible-ubuntu-latest.yml`, so that there is no empty `[]` in the hard coded inventory file. It doesn't matter what it is because it's not used anywhere else. I did that before and pushed my changes and it didn't take, and then just after waiting some time and making no other changes at all, the playbook did run. I'm baffled. So my conclusion with GitHub Actions is: if it doesn't work, wait an hour and try again.